# Calculate covariance matrix in SAS from a file instead of write manually the datas in the editor

Tags: sas

Is it possible to calculate the covariance and correlation matrix from a set of sample datas.

For example, I have store a set of datas in Sasuser.Live. 
I want to find the covariance matrix  or the correlation matrix. 
I know that I can write the data in the editor(which is very tedious) and then use proc cov.

Or I can do something like this to use the already stored datas:

```
proc princomp data= Sasuser.Live out=Sasuser.Live_Out;
var Touch Chips Driver Compatibility Game;
run;

proc print data=Mouse_Can_Out;
run;
```

but this computes more than the covariance matrix. I just want the covariance matrix and the correlation matrix.

Comment: Anything that goes to the screen can be captured and there's often OUTPUT statements or OUT statements within the PROC to generate output. Look in the documentation in the Syntax under PROC PRINCOMP statement or an explicit OUTPUT statement. Or in general, this approach will work: https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2017/01/09/ods-output-any-statistic.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `PROC CORR`?

Example:

```
proc corr noprint data=sashelp.class cov out=cov;
  var age height weight;
run;

proc print data=cov;
run;
```

Result:

```
Obs    _TYPE_    _NAME_      Age       Height     Weight

 1      COV      Age        2.2281      6.210     25.186
 2      COV      Height     6.2099     26.287    102.493
 3      COV      Weight    25.1857    102.493    518.652
 4      MEAN               13.3158     62.337    100.026
 5      STD                 1.4927      5.127     22.774
 6      N                  19.0000     19.000     19.000
 7      CORR     Age        1.0000      0.811      0.741
 8      CORR     Height     0.8114      1.000      0.878
 9      CORR     Weight     0.7409      0.878      1.000
```